# Does C# Ping (or PingReply) take the average RTT?

Tags: c#, ping

I've been looking for documentation on whether the round trip time returned in a C# PingReply is the average of multiple results or just one, and I can't seem to find an answer. Does anyone know this, or can anyone find something in the docs that I've missed?

Comment: [_"The Ping class attempts to send **an** Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) echo request to a remote computer and receive information back from the computer via an ICMP echo reply message. The Ping class uses instances of the PingReply class to return information about the operation, such as its status and the time taken to send the request and receive the reply"_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply(v=vs.110).aspx)...

Comment: Aah, thanks! Didn't read carefully enough, clearly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the round trip time which you get. You can refer the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Ping class attempts to send an Internet Control Message Protocol
>   (ICMP) echo request to a remote computer and receive information back
>   from the computer via an ICMP echo reply message. The Ping class uses
>   instances of the PingReply class to return information about the
>   operation, such as its status and the time taken to send the request
>   and receive the reply.
>
> The Send methods return instances of the PingReply class directly. The
>   SendAsync methods return a PingReply in the PingCompletedEventHandler
>   method's PingCompletedEventArgs parameter. The PingReply is accessed
>   through the Reply property.